# Pillow recognizes JPEG encoder on install, but not use

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm doing some work on a vagrant box running Ubuntu 13.04 and python 3.3.  I've installed Pillow and libjpeg-dev (installing the latter first, as recommended), and when I install (or re-install Pillow, I see this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version      Pillow 2.3.0
platform     linux 3.3.1 (default, Sep 25 2013, 19:29:01)
             [GCC 4.7.3]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** TKINTER support not available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
```

Great!  JPEG encoder recognized.  Except, when I run Pillow's selftest.py script, it fails a bunch of tests and starts off with this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Pillow 2.3.0 TEST SUMMARY 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Python modules loaded from /usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/PIL
Binary modules loaded from /usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/PIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- PIL CORE support ok
*** TKINTER support not installed
*** JPEG support not installed
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support ok
```

So now it's not recognizing the JPEG decoder.  To make sure this isn't just a problem with selftest.py, I did my testing and sure enough I can make and manipulate .pngs but not .jpgs.  I've searched around and tried some suggested solutions, including making a symbolic link to the jpg library, like so:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib
```

No dice.  Anybody have an idea of something else I could try to get the jpeg decoder working?  It really isn't practical for me to restrict the workflow entirely to .png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And, this is why I need to wait 24 hours before posting questions.  I needed to pay attention to the Pillow install path.  It works if I create the symlink like so:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/local/lib/
```

/usr/lib wasn't in the Pillow search path, but the above is.