# Find which libjpeg is being used by PIL / PILLOW

Tags: python, libjpeg, python-imaging-library

I am getting an error where reading the same lena.jpg file on two different computers yeilds two different checksums.

Even weirder is that when I run md5sum lena.jpg I get the same md5 sum on both machines, so the files are identical.

Furthermore, when I load a png instead of a jpeg the numbers seem to match up. This leads me to believe there is a disconnect between Pillow on the two different machines, or at least the library they are using to read jpeg files.

Is there any way to check which version of libjpeg is being used by Pillow (from within Python preferably)?

Both of the computers are Ubuntu, although one is 12.04, and one is 14.04 (I also tested it on a mac and got the same values as the 14.04 box)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, locate the PIL egg that your Python installation is using:

```
>>> import PIL
>>> PIL.__path__
['/usr/local/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL']
```

Then locate `_imaging.so` in that directory and use `ldd` (Linux) or `otool -L` (OS X) to find out what version of `libjpeg` it has been linked against:

**Linux**

```sh
$ ldd /usr/local/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00641000)
    libjpeg.so.62 => /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.62 (0x00f00000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x006f4000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00fad000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x0021b000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x0067e000)
```

**Mac OS X**

```sh
$ otool -L /Users/lukas/src/pillow-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
/Users/lukas/src/pillow-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so:
    /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib (compatibility version 13.0.0, current version 13.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
    /usr/local/lib/libtiff.5.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
```

Comment: Great, you wouldn't know how to do this for windows (with mingw) would you? I tried  objdump -p _imaging.pyd  | grep .dll and got:         DLL Name: KERNEL32.dll
        DLL Name: USER32.dll
        DLL Name: GDI32.dll
        DLL Name: python27.dll
        DLL Name: MSVCR90.dll
        c6f24     150  __dllonexit, which doesnt say anything about jpeg

Comment: @Erotemic No, sorry, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ldd path/to/your/PIL/_*.so
```

If you are using virtualenv, try to find PIL on your VIRTUALENV_HOME, usually it is under

```
~/.virtualenvs/$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL
```

If you are using ubuntu packages, use dpkg to find the location of your pillow/PIL install.